# PHP downloaded file starts with 7 indentaions

Tags: php, download, header, icalendar

I have this really simple PHP-Code which I broke down to the very basics.

```
header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.ics");
echo "AAA";
```

This should in theory download a file which contains nothing but "AAA" but as soon as I open the file, it will contain exactly 7 indentaions before the three "A"

[image: Indentaion]

This seems to create problems when working with certain services reading ICS so I need to remove that. I have no clue where to start. If I don't download the file but open it in the browser, there will be no indentaion.

Where do these come from?

Thank you for your help

Comment: which text editor do you use to open the file?

Comment: I've tried Notepad++, Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text, all beave the same. The default Notepad from Windows shows them aswell

Comment: Is that your full code? Are there any whitespaces outside of the PHP block, such as at the start of the file?

Comment: Try to read file binary to see what happens...

Comment: Do you have the code starting/closing php tags ( <?php ?>) in the source ? They may create problems, you may have some spaces before <?php and/or after ?>.

Comment: UTF-8...  BOM maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Hm... Turns out a "require_once" statement causes this indentaion, but it only contains <?php class classname extends othercalss{ functions }?> this should not cause any output, should it?